# How to add VKThread to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use [VKThread](http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkthread/) in React. However it doesn't appear
 to be available as an npm package. according to the instructions, they say to add `<script src="../vkthread/vkthread.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` to your project. However I don't know how I can do this in a react app.

Any help is appreciated, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a "traditional" `index.html` located in `/public`. You can add any script such as your `<script src="../vkthread/vkthread.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in the body there.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not getting "vkthread is undefined" Any idea why that's happening?